# How to plot a region under $y=\sin(x)$ in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

I would like to plot the *shaded* region between `$y=\sin(x)$` and `$y=0$` over `$x \in [0, \pi]$` using TikZ and/or possible other packages which I don't know yet. Can you give some examples?

Specifically:

how to do the computation of the special function `$\sin$`?

how to specify the region in TikZ?

how to shade the region?

Thanks and regards!

Comment: Have a look at [texample.net](http://www.texample.net/tikz/examples/animated-distributions/) for inspirations.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This is explained in the sections “15.4 Filling a Path” and “19 Plots of Functions” in the TikZ manual (numbers refer to the 2.10 version).

A simple example (note that `\x r` interprets `\x` as radians; the TikZ's `sin` function takes degrees as input):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \fill[fill=red] (pi/4,0) -- plot [domain=pi/4:3*pi/4] (\x,{sin(\x r)}) -- (3*pi/4,0) -- cycle;
    \draw plot[domain=0:pi] (\x,{sin(\x r)});

    \draw[gray,->] (-0.3,0) -- (pi+0.3,0);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: example]